# What is the behavior of C11 array initialization when descriptors overlap?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, c11, descriptor

Given this

```
int array[10] = {
[0] = 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, // 7 values
[5] = 9
};
```

gcc (6.3.1) does not generate an error or warning that the initialization overlaps.

What is the define behavior? It there supposed to be a warning or is the array initialized in order of designator occurrence?

Comment: Designated initializers were introduced in C99 and did not change in C11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *no* warning. The array is initialized in order of *designator occurrence*, so later designations override previous ones.

In your example, you first assigned the first seven values (index 0 to 6) with 1, and *then* assigned the sixth value (index 5) with 9.

Your array would contain the values (in order from index 0 to 9)

- `1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0` from the first definition, `[0] = 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,`
- `1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0` from the second, `[5] = 9`

This is also compliant to the C99 and C11 standard, as it states

> "The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each initializer provided for a particular subobject overriding any previously listed initializer for the same subobject"